# Is there a limit for local storage size in Bluemix Node JS runtime?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I'm bullding a Node JS app that will :

1-Dowload a large set of images stored at cloudant as doc attachments

2-Process this set of images

3-Build a zip file with the processed images

4-Send the zip files to an external service

5-Delete all the temp local files

My question:

The set of files can have up to 4GB (~4K files of 1MB). Is it ok to load this amount of files in a temp dir with Node runtime? Is there a size limit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default disk size for applications running on Bluemix is 1G and you can increase it a max of 2G using the `-k` option when pushing the application, for example:

```
$ cf push <my-app> -k 2G
```

In your case I suggest you to use the [Object Storage](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/index.html) service as a temporary storage to process your images and create the zip file.

With the free Object Storage service you have up to 5 GB of storage space you can use.

Another option would be to deploy your Node.js application using 
[IBM Containers](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html#container_index), which runs docker containers in Bluemix infrastructure.

Comment: With the app file system being ephemeral this is probably good advice regardless of whether or not the temporary files would fit.

Comment: Great answer. I'll probably use -k option for initial tests and move to object storage in a second momment.